# Cómo compruebo que hay información guardada en el localStorage

Tags: javascript

**Estoy guardando información en el localStorage:**

```
let save_json = { 
"name": "Juan",
"age": "20"
}
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(save_json));
```

**Estoy usando la opción *undefined* para tratar de comprobar si hay información guardada pero al momento en el que se actualiza la página es como si no hubiera nada en el localStorage ya que no ejecuta las instrucciones del if**

```
let data_save = localStorage.getItem("data");

if (data_save != undefined) {

document.write(JSON.parse(data_save).name);

}
```

Comment: O podrías haber leído la [documentación de `getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) y verías que si la clave que intentas obtener no existe devuelve `null`, y no `undefined`... O también podrías haber usado la manera *"genérica"* de comprobar si algo existe o no poniendo simplemente `if (data_save) {...`. La documentación está para leérsela, y la de javascript para navegadores es realmente completa, extensa y bien traducida. Aprender a buscar en la documentación es más importante que aprender a escribir código en realidad :) Te recomiendo usarla a menudo.

Comment: En pocas palabras `undefined !== null`. Saludos

Comment: Tu código está bien. Así que el problema debe estar en otro lado